# filesystem fd from file fd

Tags: linux, file-io, system-calls, ioctl

My program opens a file and wants to set `O_DIRECT` for it. But the program assumes block size of 512. So, I need to check for that size. `man 2 open` suggests to do it like this `ioctl(filesystem_fd, BLKSSZGET, &block_size)`.

And my question is: how to get this `filesystem_fd` from `fd` of an ordinary file?

Comment: `filesystem_fd` appears to be the name of the parameter used in your documentation.   Just pass `fd` to `ioctl`

Comment: `filesystem_fd` is the name I invented to distinguish between two fds. If I do what you suggest `ioctl()` returns `errno == ENOTTY`. So, it's not that simple.

Comment: You need to open the device.  That is, if your file is on the file system mounted at /dev/sda, you should open /dev/sda and pass that fd to ioctl.

Comment: Exactly. But how can I get this `/dev/sda` from some `fd`?

Comment: Ack.  I can't believe I wrote "mounted at /dev/sda".  Please disregard that.  You can examine `st_dev` and `st_rdev` in the stat struct, but that's not a complete answer.

Comment: But....if all you care about is the block size, then you can look at st_blksize

Comment: Thanks. I've failed to get a `filesysem_id` `st_dev`. Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that.  If you want to know the block size of the filesystem in which your file resides, just look in st_blksize.  That is:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        struct stat sb;
        char *name = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : argv[0];

        if( stat(name, &sb) == -1 ) {
                perror(name);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        printf("Block size: %d\n", (int)sb.st_blksize);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: This is not correct, sorry.

Here is your program:
gcc 1.cc && ./a.out 1.cc             
Block size: 4096

And here is the correct block size:
/sbin/blockdev --getss /dev/nvme0n1
512

Comment: `--getss` gets the sector size.  If you want the block size, use `--getbsz`

Comment: I want `--getss` because that's what `man 2 open` is about. And it calls it 'logical block size'.